# Find maximum occurrence of an year in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Here are some credit card records, I need to find the year having the maximum number of card expiry dates.
As the dates are not in `YYYY/MM/DD` format so in the schema I have defined the dates as of 'string' type

```
Card Type Full Name,Card Holder's Name,Issue Date,Expiry Date,Card PIN

Discover,Brenda D Peterson,01/2017,01/2022,1998
Diners Club International,Dawn U Reese,12/2015,12/2013,3915 
Diners Club International,Helen P Perry,02/2007,02/2020,2319
American Express,Christine E Kim,08/2011,08/2013,9017
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the year with highest number of records.

```
select 
   substr(expiry_date, instr(expiry_date, '/')+1) as expiry_year,
   count(*) as cnt
from customers
group by substr(expiry_date, instr(expiry_date, '/')+1)
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

There are chances that more than 1 year has same number of cards expiring that year in such cases you can use below query

```
select 
   substr(expiry_date, instr(expiry_date, '/')+1) as expiry_year
from customers
having count(*) = (
   select max(cnt) from (
      select 
         substr(expiry_date, instr(expiry_date, '/')+1) as expiry_year,
         count(*) as cnt
      from customers
         group by substr(expiry_date, instr(expiry_date, '/')+1)
   )t
);
```